# Why is the fixed field of this automorphism $\mathbb Q(\pi^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\sigma:\mathbb Q(\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb Q(\pi)$ be an automorphism fixing $\mathbb Q$ such that $\sigma(\pi)=-\pi$.

Let $F$ be the fixed field. Then it is obvious that $\mathbb Q(\pi^2)\subset F$. However, why is $F=\mathbb Q(\pi^2)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the fixed field $F$. (1) The extension $\mathbf{Q}(\pi)/F$ is generated by $\pi$ which is quadratic algebraic  over $F$ (as it is the square root of the element $\pi^2\in F$). Also $\mathbf{Q}(\pi)/\mathbf{Q}(\pi^2)$  is quadratic for the same reason. Now you can see that $F/\mathbf{Q}(\pi^2) $ is of degree 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_nx^n\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , and $\;f(\pi)\in\Bbb Q(\pi)\;$ . Then,

$$\sigma(f(\pi))=f(-\pi)\implies f(\pi)\in\Bbb Q(\pi)^\sigma\iff a_r=0\;\;\text{for all odd}\;\;0\le r\le n $$

and from here follows the claim.