# $K$-monomorphism that is not $K$-automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, galois-theory, monomorphisms

I am confused by the terminology where $K$ precedes terms such as $K$-monomorphism and $K$-automorphism in Galois theory. I am trying to come up with a simple example about $K$-monomorphism that is not $K$-automorphism to understand the purpose of preceding the words such as the monomorphism with the field $K$. How is the example different from example without the preceding $K$ in the terms such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154716/an-example-for-a-homomorphism-that-is-not-an-automorphism)?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't the first linked question answer this, with $K=\Bbb Q$ and $$T:\Bbb Q(x)\to\Bbb Q(x)\\ T(f(x)):=f(x^2)$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Good point! I am confused by the terminology of Galois theory. Why does Galois Theory use the word K-monomorphism instead of the word monomorphism? What is the purpose of preceding the words with $K$-something?

Comment: @hhh The prefix tells you that the homomorphism keeps all elements of $K$ fixed. For instance, $\mathbb{C}$ has just two $\mathbb{R}$-automorphisms, but infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms.

Comment: If $L/K$ and $M/K$ are extensions then a $K$-morphism is a morphism $L\to M$ with $x\mapsto x$ if $x\in K$. Actually any morphism between fields can be classified as a monomorphism (they are injective). A $K$-morphism can be an isomorphism, wich comes to being surjective as well. If in that case also $L=M$ then you are dealing with a $K$-automorphism. This will be always be the case if the extension is algebraic (weaker than finite). So what you need is an extension that is not algebraic.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: 1. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242595/why-is-the-fixed-field-of-this-automorphism-mathbb-q-pi2

2. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151878/k-monomorphism-l-rightarrow-l-is-k-automorphism-if-finite-extension-lk

Comment: A homomorphism f of fields is always injective, since f(1) is required to be 1 (and you must require it, because if not, what's the difference between rings and fields ?) A K-homomorphism means implicitly a homomorphism f between 2 extensions L/K and L'/K which fixes K pointwise. If L and L' have the same finite K-dimension, then f is automatically a K-isomorphism. But f is NOT a K-iso. if dim L' is strictly greater than dim L (think of non normal extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Consider subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.  The polynomial $X^3 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Hence $F = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-2)$ is field.  The roots of $X^3-2$ are $\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega \sqrt[3]{2},$ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{4}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity.  The ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}), X \mapsto \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2})$ are both surjective with kernel $(X^3-2)$, hence there are isomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-2) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}), \mathbb{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2})$.  By composing, we get an isomorphism of fields $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2})$$ given by $\sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ which is actually a $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphism.  But this is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism, since that would say that the fields are literally equal, not just isomorphic.